# Pause loop until inner function returns (C#)

Tags: c#, for-loop, dataset

I have a loop that I don't want to continue until `LoadAmazonDataByBatch()` has returned. I know there must be a straight forward way of doing it, and I'm almost certain I'm approaching the problem wrong.

```c
const int batchSize = 500;
for (int i = 0; i < total; i = i + batchSize)
{
    LoadAmazonDataByBatch(i, batchSize, fileList, total, amazonLogHandler, stopWatch);
}
```

`LoadAmazonDataByBatch()` does a bunch of things on worker threads including creating a temporary DataSet that would get very large without the batching. I don't want to create a new DataSet until the old one is processed and disposed (by LoadAmazonDataByBatch).
Obviously the way this is written now everything happens almost all at once.

How can I approach this better?

Comment: What does `LoadAmazonDataByBatch` look like?  Can you change the method?  Does it have a callback?  If the method doesn't give a way of letting you know when it's finished, then it may not be possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do some sort of thread synchronization.

Not clear where you got the `LoadAmazonByBatch()` , but I'd suggest

- checking the doc for that function to see if there is a synchronous version of the operation.
- if no doc is available, then you will need to roll up yr sleeves. It may require viewing or modifying the source of `LoadAmazonByBatch()`.  Look for a `ManualResetEvent` that is set by the workers when they are finished. Or, maybe there is a regular .NET event that is emitted by that method when it completes.  If those things don't exist you'll need to add something like that.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I implemented `LoadAmazonByBatch()` and it uses a single `Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>` in each call to do its work (reading from a file, then saving to dataset, then loading to SQL).

Comment: ok, then you need to decide if you want the asynchronous behavior.  Task.Factory lets you run things in the background, but now you are saying *you don't want that.*  I suspect that there are some benefits to loading asynchronously within that fn (specifically asynch http requests), so I'd suggest adding thread synch capability. Do the `Task.WaitAll()` optionally, within `LoadAmazonByBatch()`, depending on a method parameter.

Comment: I'll give this a shot. I do the work in the background to avoid hanging the UI thread.

Comment: well, ok, but .. doing `Task.Wait()` will ... ahh... **wait** ... for the background work to complete.  If you are doing `Task.Wait()` on the UI thread, the UI thread will hang.  So you need to think a little more about exactly what you're trying to accomplish. Seems like you want the thing that runs the loop to be NOT on the UI thread. That itself should be kicked off by `Task.StartNew()`.  Then, the loop runs in the bg thread. Put a `Task.WaitAll()` in `LoadAmazonByBatch()` and you'll get only one large dataset at a time.

Comment: Yea you're right. What I did was remove the background thread creation out of `LoadAmazonData()`, and wrapped the whole loop with a new thread `Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>`. Works well and the function no longer steps on its own toes. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It's very likely that LoadAmazonDataByBatch creates a bunch of threads. You have to call Join on all created threads to wait till they complete.

Comment: may not be possible if the implementation uses QueueUserWorkItem(), as it should.

Comment: Each LoadAmazon call uses `Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>{...` to do some work.

Comment: Then you need `Task.Wait()` or `Task.WaitAll()`.

Answer (score 0):

Surely the only way this *wouldn't* wait for the function to return is if it's written asynchronously?

The relevant code isn't the loop you posted, it's the definition of `LoadAmazonDataByBatch()` that we need to see.

Comment: You are correct, but this is more of a comment than an answer.

Answer (score 0):

If that function has a callback (stopWatch?), perhaps you could call the function (LoadAmazonDataByBatch) within the callback.

Answer (score 0):

If `LoadAmazonDataByBatch()` generates child threads, and it runs until each of those threads is finished, you can use the `Thread.Join()` method to make it wait for the child threads to finish.  I am not sure how that would work for multiple children but I think it should be OK.

Reference: [Threading in C#](http://www.albahari.com/threading/)